# Adding to the prototype of an instance of another prototype: JavaScript

Tags: javascript, prototype

My question is simply:

How do I set up the prototype of a class that inherits from another class's prototype?

My code below works until I try to call Pierre.mySkill(), at which point the console says that the function is undefined.

My reason for this, theoretically, is to be able to create instances of Pirault, and also instances of Person, and be able to add to Pirault's prototype without having to add to Person's.

```
function Person (name, age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

Person.prototype.info = function(){
    console.log('I am '+this.name+' and I am '+this.age+' years old.');
};

function Pirault (){
    this.skill = arguments[2];

    Person.apply(this, arguments);
}

Pirault.prototype.mySkill = function(){
    console.log('My skill is '+this.skill);
}

Pirault.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Pirault.prototype.constructor = Pirault;

var Pierre = new Pirault('Pierre', 30, 'Programming');
```

Comment: So `skill` is `"Pierre"`?

Comment: woops!  Thanks for catching that, I meant to update it before I posted.

Comment: Here is a simplified version of your problem: `var foo = {}; foo.name = 'foo'; foo = {}; console.log(foo.name);`. It should be pretty obvious why `foo.name` returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Organize your code so that all the prototype methods are defined *after* the prototype object is created. For example:

```
Pirault.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Pirault.prototype.constructor = Pirault;

Pirault.prototype.mySkill = function(){
    console.log('My skill is '+this.skill);
}
```

[**<kbd>Demo</kbd>**](http://jsfiddle.net/bky3b1no/). As it stands, you correctly define a method on the prototype - but then lose it, when an object (created by `Object.create`) becomes a new `Pirault.prototype`.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative approach you don't need constructors to do this. All you need in modern browsers are objects and `Object.create`:

```
var Person = {
  info: function() {
    console.log('I am '+ this.name +'and I am '+ this.age +' years old.')
  }
}

var Pirault = Object.create(Person)
Pirault.mySkill = function() {
  console.log('My skill is '+ this.skill)
}

var pierre = Object.create(Pirault)
pierre.name = 'Pierre'
pierre.age = 30
pierre.skill = 'Programming'

pierre.mySkill() //=> My skill is Programming

console.log(Pirault.isPrototypeOf(pierre)) //=> true
console.log(Person.isPrototypeOf(pierre)) //=> true
```

Comment: This approach works well if all the base objects are 'interfacial' (ahem) - i.e., only contain methods to work on. Otherwise one has to instantiate them too, and that can get messy, in my opinion. Still, nice approach, +1 from me. )

Comment: ONE THOUSAND THANK YOUS.  If I could upvote you more than once, I would.  You can't imagine how many articles I read promoting the Class/constructor/new-based approach and I always felt like something was "not quite right"...

Comment: Actually, there's more than one way to organize the objects' hierarchy - for example, mixins (`Base.call(this)`).

Comment: raina77ow, I need to understand what you're saying.  What does it mean that the objects "only contain methods to work on."  I want to understand under which circumstance this method is not preferable.  Thanks!

Comment: @papiro It's really a long talk, and I feel I won't be able to explain it in the SO answer (let alone in the comment). Note the difference, though: in your case, you didn't assign properties on `pierre` - you just passed it up into the base's constructor class with `Person.apply(this, arguments)` line. With the approach given in this answer, it's not so - setting up properties on Object's instances is the responsibility of the client, the one that creates that instance.

Comment: @papiro May I recommend you reading [this wonderful book](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#designpatternsjavascript) of Addy Osmani? In my opinion, it explains the difference - and potential use-cases - for different Creational patterns in JS pretty darn well. )

Comment: You are the man;  last night I was looking for e-books on "JavaScript Patterns" and I came across three different ones and couldn't decide which one I should choose (I ain't got all the time in the world, ya know).  I shall start reading Osmani's tonight :-)